# Search API based on specific to TITLE(system.title)

Tags: rest, azure-devops

https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/search/workitemsearchresults?api-version=5.1-preview.1

**HTTP REQUEST:**

```
Content:  {
  "searchText": "${search}",
  "$skip": 0,
  "$top": 100,
  "filters": {
    "System.WorkItemType": [
      "Issue"
    ],
    "System.State": [
      "Doing",
      "To Do"
    ]
  },
  "$orderBy": [
    {
      "field": "system.id",
      "sortOrder": "ASC"
    }
  ],
  "includeFacets": false
}
```

this searching the whole board, is there a way to add a filter just to search on title(system.title) itself, i have tried adding the filter system.title it doesnt work

Scenario:  if i want to search "ABC" from REST API it is returning the result even if "ABC" exists in description of the story or discussion of the story....so is there a way to search and return the results just based on title and not anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a work item query with wiql [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Wiql example:

```
SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'ProjectName'
  AND  [System.Title] CONTAINS 'Search Text' ORDER BY [System.Id]
```

Guidance for wiql: [Syntax for the Work Item Query Language (WIQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops)

Comment: so if my search should be based on system.title, how should i write that...I meant it should return me the result based on the search on only on system.title but not the whole body....and is there a specific API used for that

Comment: @rahul My example contains search in system.title only: `[System.Title] CONTAINS 'Search Text'`.

Comment: You can add any additional field into the `where` clause. For the description: `SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'ProjectName'  AND  [System.Title] CONTAINS 'Search Text' AND  [System.Description] CONTAINS 'Search Text' ORDER BY [System.Id]`

Comment: and what is the API i should be using for it?

Comment: {
  "searchText": "${search}",
  "$skip": 0,
  "$top": 100,
  "filters": {
    "System.WorkItemType": [
      "Issue"
    ],

    "System.State": [
      "Doing",
      "To Do"
    ]
  },
  "$orderBy": [
    {
      "field": "system.id",
      "sortOrder": "ASC"
    }
  ],
  "includeFacets": false
}

SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.Title] CONTAINS ''Search Text'']  ...CAN I USE SOMETHING LIKE THIS

Comment: @rahul It was pointed in my first link [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204687/discussion-between-rahul-and-shamrai-aleksander).

Comment: can you pls help me with a query which refines the search i.e.  the query should search the exact words and not CONTAINS ([System.Title] CONTAINS 'Search Text')

Comment: something like IS ([System.Title], i have tried that but it doesn't recognize the query i think "IS"  is not recognized